# Ajax PHP based simple forum

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, forum

I have to use php,mysql to do  a prroject.I have chosen to make a simple forum and use a lot of Ajax with it.since i am still a novice, can you guide me to a simple ajax guestbook which i can work on to make a forum? i want to end up with something like this but even simpler. http://board.fuzzylime.co.uk/

Answer (score 3):

It's not terribly complex. Just set up a MySQL database, and use a PHP script to connect to it, check for a login, and add a record for a post or list records to view a post.

Answer (score 2):

If you are just starting out, I would suggest that you first understand the basics of building a forum in PHP.

Personally I liked the forum example in [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672326728) . I thought it was explained very well. You can also just google for "PHP forum tutorial" to find a couple examples, like [this one](http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/12.html) and [this one](http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/12.html).

Once you have the basic idea figured out you can start looking at how to make an AJAX style implementation. For that, you can also just google AJAX tutorials and go from there. Either way, I think if you are going to build a forum, its important to understand the basics behind building a forum before jumping into a more complicated example like an AJAX driven one. Understanding the PHP portion of the application, and the database behind the whole thing is a very important step.